# Passing shell variable into file read by cat

Tags: html, shell, sendmail

Long time viewer first time poster.

I don't know unix or shell at all, I'm just trying to create some notifications based on a SQL query I have written to support a Wordpress site I have built.

I want to send an html email based on my query.
The query returns something like;

```
+------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|display_name| user_email    | value    | type     |
+------------+---------------+----------+----------+ 
| nick       | nick@test.com | somedata | batch1   |
| bob        | bob@test.com  | somedata | batch2   |
+------------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

Here's my code

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASS DB -N < /path/to/file/batch.sql | while read user_email display_name value type ; do

emailtemplate="/path/to/file/email.html"  
(  
echo "From: email@address.com"  
echo "To: $user_email"  
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"  
echo "Subject: Test"   
echo "Content-Type: text/html"   
cat $emailtemplate  
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t

sleep 5

done
```

I need to change the $emailtemplate based on the $type variable, apart from that this is all working except I can't pass the $display_name and $value variables to the html file, it just appears as $display_name and $value in the email.

Please help! I know it's something really minor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Seems variables aren't recognised, so a find/replace with a unique value works.

instead of

```
cat $emailtemplate
```

this works by have %%display_name%% and %%value%% in the template so that they can be replace with the variables

```
sed -e "s/%%display_name%%/$display_name/" -e "s/%%value%%/$value/" $emailtemplate
```